# Is PostGIS-2.x raster in text format (WKT) only?

Tags: raster, postgis-2.0

I was reading [PostGIS FAQ](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_FAQ.html) and  [this tutorial](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/WKTRasterTutorial01). From all that I can tell, it seems that PostGIS raster is a text format, i.e. WKT or well-known-text. I was wondering if PostGIS raster data are text-formatted only, or if there is also a binary format PostGIS raster.

If it's only WKT, does that mean PostGIS rasters are potentially more space consuming and slower to load and display (than a regular grid of binary values)?

---

I am asking because I am thinking about whether to use PostGIS raster for e.g. a webgis, and whether choosing PostGIS raster will lead to a performance hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the exchange format that the database emits and consumes with the internal format that it uses to store on disk. Check out the [serialized format RFC](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/svn-trunk/raster/doc/RFC1-SerializedFormat) to learn about the on-disk binary form.

Comment: OK, so why the mentioned documents keep saying PostGIS WKT raster? Did I misunderstand the WKT part? I know e.g. you can export binary shapefiles to WKT, and we don't say ESRI WKT shapefile. Also, is the (de-)serialization for text or binary data.

Comment: In the beginning is was called WKTRaster and that old name still stays in various places like in http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/WKTRaster.